# Jquery File Upload Firing Unobtrusive Form Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am using the jquery file upload plugging to upload a logo image. The file input is inside an MVC Razor view form. The current behavior of the upload is to as soon as an image is selected it get post to the server and gets converted to a base64 string and gets returned back as string via json to be stored on a hidden field and an img tag, in order to display the uploaded image. Later the image get saved with the rest of the form fields.

This implementation works perfect on IE10, IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, but in IE8 when I select the file, the unobtrusive validation for all form fields, gets fired prior posting the image to the server. This behavior force the user to fill all form fields prior selecting an image.

Below is the code:

MVC View

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@( "/MenuTemplate/Index/" & Model.ClientLocationId)" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="logo">
            <label>Logo:</label><img id="imgLogo" src='@IIF(Model.Logo IsNot Nothing, "data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64," & Model.Logo, String.Empty)' onerror='this.style.display = "none"'  />
            <input id="LogoFile" type="file" name="files" accept="image/jpeg,image/JPEG,image/jpg,image/JPG,image/png,image/PNG"/>
            @Html.ValidationMessage("file")
            <a id="btnRemoveLogo" href="#" class="icon" title="REMOVE LOGO"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.TemplateName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.TemplateName, New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {{"id", "txtTemplateName"}, {"class", "trackChanges"}, {"style", "width:210px"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.TemplateName)
        </div>
        <div class="color">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Color)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Color,  New Dictionary (Of String , Object )() From  { { "class", "colorpickerinput trackChanges" }, { "tabindex", "-1" }, { "tabstop", "false" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Color)
        </div>
        <div class="type">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.MenuTypeId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.MenuTypeId, Enumerable.Empty(Of SelectListItem)(), New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {{"class", "ddlMenuTypeId trackChanges"}, {"style", "width:210px"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.MenuTypeId)
        </div>
         <div class="type">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.DisclosureId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.DisclosureId, Enumerable.Empty(Of SelectListItem)(), New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {{"class", "ddlDisclosureId trackChanges"}, {"style", "width:210px"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.DisclosureId)
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Description)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(m) m.Description, New Dictionary(Of String, Object)() From {{"class", "trackChanges"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Description)
        </div>

</form>
```

JS CODE

```
 //Upload Image
$('#LogoFile').fileupload({
    forceIframeTransport: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/postLogoImage?Id=' + Id,
    done: function (e, data) {

        try {
            var errorflag = false;
            $.each(data.files, function (index, item) {                    
                var fname = item.name;
                var ext = fname.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

                if ($.inArray(ext, ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
                    dialogNotification('Invalid image type. Please use .jpg, .png only.!');
                    errorflag = true;
                    return;
                }
            });
            if (errorflag === true)
                return;
            if (!data.result.error) {
                var returnedImageString = data.result.files[0];

                $('#imgLogo').attr('src', "data:image/jpg;charset=utf-8;base64," + returnedImageString);
                $('#imgLogo').show();
                $('#hLogo').val(returnedImageString);
                $('#btnRemoveLogo').show();
                SetRecordChangeFlag(true);
            }
            else {
                var errs = data.result;
                dialogNotification(errs.message);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        dialogNotification('Invalid image type. Please use .jpg, .png only.');
    }
});
```

Thanks for the Help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
$(function() {  
 var validationSettings = $.data($('form').get(0), 'validator').settings;  
 validationSettings.ignore = '.ignore, #LogoFile, :hidden, :disabled';
});
```

Comment: In my case, it doesn't. Ignoring the input of type file has the effect of not validating the that control. However, selecting a file still triggers the validation of the other input controls. Ignoring the title input works, in that the validation does not complain, but you'll loose client-side validation completely.